# Given past cone $C$, does a point exist that is spacelike to every point in $C$?

Tags: general-relativity

This is a question, hopefully quite basic, about the global structure of current GR models of our universe.

Let $q$ be a point in spacetime with past light cone $C_q$, and let $p$ be a point in $q$'s timelike past, having past light cone $C_p \subseteq C_q$.

Does there exist a point $x \in C_q$ that is *spacelike* to every point in $C_p$ (excepting the least point in the causal ordering, if there is one)?

(No such $x$ would exist if we were talking about flat Minkowski space, but I'm asking about the plausible GR models of our universe, with which I am far less familiar.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "is spacelike"? In any spacetime with at least 2 spatial dimensions, there's always a spacelike curve relating any two points, even if the two points are also timelike related.

If you mean that the two points aren't timelike related, just consider a spacetime with a timelike segment removed from spacetime, and pick $p$ to the left of this segment and another point to the right. With the right choice of point no point of $p$'s past will be related to the other point.

As for cosmological models, I think this is possible, with the right parametrization of the FRW model. Just pick a point outside of the particle horizon of $p$ and it will be spacelike separated from $J^-(p)$.

Comment: This is a wrong answer. "... a timelike segment removed from spacetime", this is the past light cone that is infinitely large in space in the infinite past. The OP is correct that there is no horizon in the Minkowski space (except for Rindler). The actual question was about cosmology and your answer is wrong again. There is no horizon shortly after the Big Bang (except perhaps for the infinite Big Bang version), "the universe increased in size by a factor of more than $10^22$, from a small and *causally connected* region", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizon_problem#Inflationary_model